# Python wget bypass checkbox before download

Tags: python, wget

So I am trying to download a file from a website namely the jdk to automate a workstation setup. When downloading from the oracle website you are forced to accept the TOS.

My question is, How exactly do you accept the TOS from python wget?

```
import wget
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

url = "https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11.0.1+13/90cf5d8f270a4347a95050320eef3fb7/jdk-11.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe"
wget.download(url, 'java11.exe')
```

Comment: I take for granted you know the issues with the new Oracle license and the switch to OpenJDK? (if not, see [here](https://blog.joda.org/2018/09/do-not-fall-into-oracles-java-11-trap.html)) There is a reason if Oracle does not want users to download blindly. And if you want to redistribute the Oracle JDK, you should contact Oracle.

Comment: I know the whole licensing thing that's going on with oracle, and I don't want to redistribute it. We just need to automate the workstation setup including java which was already approved by our legal department

Comment: Then why not download the JDK once and for all? Downloading from a fixed link isn't going to provide a newer version, so I don't see the point (and that's why I thought there was an issue with the question). Usually for internal purposes there is either a "master" for all computers, or at least a common network directory to put the install programs.

Comment: Good point, I literally forgot about making a master resource system which I agree should be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

With the `wget` module you cannot set cookies, which the Oracle website uses to accept the TOS.

Instead, you can use the `requests` module to set cookies, download, and save the file.

```
import requests

url = 'https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11.0.1+13/90cf5d8f270a4347a95050320eef3fb7/jdk-11.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe'

cookie = { 'oraclelicense': 'accept-securebackup-cookie' }

r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookie)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open("jdk-11.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe", 'wb') as file:
        file.write(r.content)
```

EDIT: I see you're also connecting through unverified SSL, to do this with `requests`, you can set `verify` to False:

```
r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookie, verify=False)
```

Comment: There are two problems with this: you must have a valid cookie and as I understand the question, it's meant to make an automated setup: the cookie won't be valid anymore. Much worse: this button is here to ask the user to accept a fairly restrictive license (the license changed with JDK 11). It's not a good idea (and probably illegal) to force the end user to install something without telling him what the restrictions will be.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I understand what you are coming from but this piece of software is only internal and it's installed on the workstation by administrators. The Java restrictive license was already approved by our company so all we need is to automate the setup on *company computers*. You can imagine what it means doing this for hundreds of PCs manually